# How can I create many variables dynamically

Tags: jquery, cookies

I need create many variables dynamically and add this variables in the cookie

**Thus:**

```
$.cookie("matrizTela", null);
  objCookie = {};
  for(var i = 1; i<vList.length;i++){
    for(var z=0;z<vList[i].length;z++){
        listaY = vList[i][z].childNodes[0].attributes;
        listaX = vList[i][z].style;
        $.each(listaY,function(key,val){
            objCookie[val.nodeName] = val.nodeValue;
        });
        //Here i need change name variable "CK" to auto increment (ck1,ck2..ckN)          
        ck = JSON.stringify(objCookie);
    }
  };
```

**Need this:**

```
$.cookie("matrizTela", [ck1,ck2,ck3..ckN]);
```

How can i make this ?

Comment: You're trying to create an **array**.

Comment: need to recover a matrix by cookie, can not do it?

Comment: You need to create an array.

Comment: How can i make this ?
I have matrix vList.. but i can not serialize this

Comment: Thank you my friend, i try array and worked, thank you :D